# How to Delete sent SMS with limit more than 500 android?

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I followed [this](http://wisdomitsol.com/blog/android/sms/programmatically-delete-all-messages-in-android) to Delete SMS..

So here I am using these

```
mContext.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null);
```

I have a [SMS sending app](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/sms-messaging-android) It sends more than 1k messages every hour

Now the problem is that In new/big phone its working fine, But when I installed same in a basic android phone with less internal memory / less SMS storage,  I am facing NO_PDU error

So I want to delete it programmatically, but with LIMIT 500 sms or past 1 day sms or past 1 hr SMS.

Answer (score 0):

mContext.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null);

The above code will delete all the sms present in SmsProvider . To delete specific sms query SmsProvider and do your operation on selected rows.

Refer below example-

```
if (values.getAsInteger(Sms.TYPE) == Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_DRAFT) {
                SqliteDatabase.delete(TABLE_SMS, "thread_id=? AND type=?",
                        new String[] { values.getAsString(Sms.THREAD_ID),
                                       Integer.toString(Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_DRAFT) });
            }
```

Comment: Thanks @ Durgesh... It sends more than 1000 sms in Hr so its difficult to find id.. Some of them fail so Its may cause error on server side if delete with id,,,